# Audio on Chrome for mobile isn't working using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I tried to play some sound (wav, ogg) using HTML5  with JavaScript on Chrome for mobile, but it's not working. I even tried a "fake" click, but nothing happened.

```
$(document).on("click", "#audio", function(){
    var a = $('#audio');
    if(a.length !== 0){
        a.get(0).play();
    }
});
$('#audio').click();
```

or

```
var audio = new Audio("file.ogg");
audio.play();
```

HTML

```
<audio controls="controls" id="audio" class="hidden">
   <source src="file.wav"></source>
</audio>
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the relevant html?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
$('some-button').on('click', function(){
    $('audio')[0].play();
});
```

In other words - use a button to receive the click and then find the `audio` element and make it start playing.

There is a small, somewhat specialized example here:

http://jsbin.com/arecoq/84

Note that the music is licensed under Creative Commons BY-CC-SA, see [further info here](http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Paper_Navy/All_Grown_Up/08_Swan_Song).

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I need to play audio without any user interaction.

Comment: That should be possible on some browsers, but you can't make it work on iOS.

Comment: Just add something like this: ``$(document).ready(function(){$('audio')[0].play()})``.